# Make RDoc parse unchanged files too

Tags: ruby, rdoc

Is there any parameter to rdoc that tells it to include all unchanged files again, too?

Calling rdoc a second (third, fourth) time, just parses the files that have been changed and index.html only shows the content of this parsed file. The other files are still available in the subdirectory but not shown.

Might be an easy thing - but I can't find a solution.

Thanks for a hint...:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try..

```
rake rerdoc                          # Force a rebuild of the RDOC files
```

Or maybe just

```
rdoc -U
```

Though I am not sure if the second one really will do what you need.